# Unable to utilize imported topoJson file for custom map visualization in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

After converting shapefile from mapshaper.org and importing it to Power BI I'm getting the below data structure in power query. I have seen countless custom map tutorials where the data is loaded straightaway to power query but I cannot seem to understand how to make this structure work. Can anyone please help me with this?

Data can be found here: [data link: radacad.com](https://radacad.com/shape-map-better-than-the-filled-map)

[image: As seen on power query]

Comment: Do you want to add it to a shape map? If you do you don't load it this way via power query

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the imported topoJSON file in the Power BI Shape map visual, you do not import it via Power Query. It is imported via the option in the visual in the Shape '+Add Map' option.

You then need another dataset that you can drag into the location field of the Shape map to map the data.

Hope that helps

[image]

Comment: Thank you Jonee for the solution. I was importing the file as json which was wrong.